# Disable object automatic dragging after duplication

Tags: objects, customization

After duplication, objects automaticaly follow the mouse pointer, is there a way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/duplicate.html) when you duplicate an object in Blender..

> ..this will create a visually identical copy of the selected object(s).
>   The copy is created at the same position as the original object and
>   **you are automatically placed in Grab mode**..

I don't think this is possible out of the box with Blender the way you are asking. At most, you can hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> after you duplicate an object or right click to cancel the grab.

---

If you insist however, it is possible to write a small script and add this to the *3D View*'s header and register shortcuts etc.

Looking at the [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_1/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.duplicate), I found a function `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()` that says *Duplicate selected objects*. You can put this into a small script and register some shortcuts for ease of use. *(it's not perfect code but it works)*

```
import bpy

class Duplicate(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.duplicate_no_drag"
    bl_label = "Duplicate"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = scene.objects.active
        bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Duplicate.bl_idname)

addon_kmaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Duplicate)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new(Duplicate.bl_idname, 'D', 'PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
    addon_kmaps.append(km)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Duplicate)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    for km in addon_kmaps:
        wm.keyconfigs.addon.kmaps.remove(km)
    del addon_kmaps[:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you run this, you should get a new menu item.

[image]

Additionally, you can call it with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and you should now be able to duplicate objects and not enter *grab* mode.

---

Also, while writing this script, it's worth noting that if you use the console or the text editor and run the command that is behind the default 'duplicate objects' command..

```
bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move()
```

it duplicates the selected object and doesn't enter grab mode. This is because of the context that's given to the operator to run in. In the *3D View* it is run in the context `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'` if you run it from a script or from the console it gets run in the context `'EXEC_DEFAULT'`. Look at the [API reference](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_67_release/bpy.ops.html?highlight=operator%20calls#execution-context) for more info about this. Thanks to [jasperge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/668/jasperge) for the explanation.

Comment: Nice! that objects duplication feels more natural to me.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go into your *Edit > Preferences*
2. Search for the command *Duplicate*,
3. Open tab *Duplicate Objects* under *Object Mode*,
4. Erase the `_move` part in the command text.
5. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]